# Single trace partition function

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory

I would be glad if someone can help me understand the argument in appendix B.1 and B.2 (page 76 to 80) of [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0310285).

The argument in B.1 supposedly helps understand how the authors in that paper got from equation 3.6 to 3.8 on page 18 of the same paper. These 3 equations form the crux of the calculation done in this paper and unfortunately I am unable to see this.

In the appendix B.2 they calculate certain rational functions which are completely mysterious to me. Like I can't understand what it means to say that $\frac{1}{1-x}$ is the partition function of the operator $\partial$. Similarly one can see such functions in the equations B.7, B.8 and B.10 of that paper.

Curiously these polynomials had also appeared on page 6 and 7 in [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9908001) long before the above paper. I am completely unable to understand how the series of polynomials between equation 15 to 20 of this paper were gotten and what they mean.

I haven't seen any book ever discuss the methods being used here. I would be glad to hear of some pedagogic and expository references on the background of all this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Their convention for the partition function is explained in the second paragraph before the equation (B.7) of the paper by Shiraz et al.  It is
$$z(x) = \sum_{operators} x^{\Delta_{operator}}$$
Note that this is just a different way of writing the usual $\mbox{Tr }\exp(-\beta H)$ if you identify $\exp(-\beta)\equiv x$ and $\Delta\equiv H$. Yes, the dimension is the same thing as the Hamiltonian (of the radial quantization) and it is often helpful to avoid exponentials and write powers of $x$ only, so therefore the exponential redefinition of $\beta$ vs $x$. The trace is the summation over the basis.

They're calculating the partition function of a whole theory, not the $\partial$ operator itself. So the partition function is the sum over operators, as described above. In this simple case, the operators are $\partial_i \partial_j \dots \phi$, i.e. arbitrary derivatives of $\phi$ by $d$ different partial derivative symbols.

The derivatives with respect to different directions commute with each other and are completely independent. So imagine $d=1$ for a while, only one direction. In that case, you have operators 
$$\phi, \partial \phi, \partial^2 \phi, \dots$$
and their dimensions are
$$\Delta=0,1,2,\dots$$
plus the dimension of $\phi$ if it were nonzero. The partition sum is the sum of $x^\Delta$ over these operators which means
$$1+x+x^2+\dots = \frac{1}{1-x}.$$
The sum is obtained as geometric series. Note that the coefficients of the Taylor expansion are simply equal to one: there is no source where you could have gotten something else.

Now, the operators in the $d$-dimensional space may be obtained by acting with some derivatives in the 1st direction; some in 2nd, and so forth, on $\phi$. So the space of operators is a tensor product of spaces from each of the $d$ directions, and the partition sum is therefore the product of the partition sums from the individual directions, i.e. the $d$-th power of $1/(1-x)$.

There are other factors multiplying the total partition function but you haven't asked about it, and I can't explain every detail in a 50-page paper you haven't asked about. But yes, the other paper you mentioned almost certainly uses the same basic insight about the geometric series.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The partition function as defined initially is a trace of a single operator (namely $x^H$) which is basically sum over expectation values of it over a basis. Can you kindly explain why this is the same as summing over $x$ raised to the scaling dimension of all the operators allowed in the theory? I wonder if this has anything to do with the fact that after Eucleadianizing the confomal theory what behaves as a   hamiltonian is not the $0-th$ component of the momentum operator but a sum of that with the $0-$ component of the special conformal transformations.

Comment: But I can't carry this argument to its logical end to prove  the implied equality as $Tr x^H = \sum _{operators} x^{\Delta _ {operators}}$. May be you can give me references towards this.